# Prove $h = r \cos\theta + r$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, circles

The triangle XYZ is inscribed by a circle with a radius,
$r$ cm. The actual placement of the triangle is dependent
on the size of the angle XZY, $\theta$ radians, and the
length of ZM, where M is the midpoint
of XY.

[image]

I need to prove that $h = r\cos\theta + r$.
Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Because $\triangle OYZ$ is isosceles, you have that $\angle OYZ = \angle OZY = \theta/2.$  This implies that $\angle OYM + \theta/2 + \theta/2 = 90^\circ \implies \angle OYM = 90^\circ - \theta.$    Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I can take it from here! I just wanted to clarify that triangle OYZ is isosceles because of the same radius length on both sides OZ and OY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show that $\angle MOY=\angle XZY$ and thus $\triangle OMY$ is a right triangle. This applies that $OM = r \cos \theta$ by $\cos \theta =\frac{adjacent}{hypotenuse}$.